# Cucumber integration to build scenarios using existent steps. Does it exist?

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, cucumber

I started to use cucumber.io (with ruby) to test my api and website.

I want to have a tool where non-tech people can create their own test scenarios based on existent steps. Some web gui tool where you can see all existent steps and just click to add a step to a scenario. Than execute the scenario you have just created.

Is there such tool? Can you recommend something?